# Manually adding data to a namespaced model in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, namespaces

I'm trying to manually add data to a table in rails using the rails console, but I keep getting a `undefined local variable or method` error.

The model is namespaced under `ratings`:

**models/ratings/value_for_money_score.rb**

```
class Ratings::ValueForMoneyScore < ApplicationRecord
end
```

To try and manually add a record to the database, I run the following in the console:

```
$ RatingsValueForMoneyScore.create(score: '1', description:"Terrible, definitely not worth what was paid!")
```

And I get this error: `NameError: uninitialized constant RatingsValueForMoneyScore`

I have tried a few different versions such as
`RatingsValueForMoneyScores.create`,
`Ratings_ValueForMoneyScores.create`, 
`ratings_value_for_money_scores.create` but keep getting the same error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you need to do `Ratings::ValueForMoneyScore.create(score: '1', description:"Terrible, definitely not worth what was paid!")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was a combination of input, so collecting that in one answer.

My namespaces weren't properly set up (I was using "Ratings" rather than "Rating"), so I fixed this for the tables. My models then looked as follows:

**models/rating.rb**

```
class Rating < ApplicationRecord
end
```

**models/rating/value_for_money_score.rb**

```
class Rating::ValueForMoneyScore < ApplicationRecord
end
```

And then this command worked for creating records in the `rating_value_for_money_score` table

```
$ Rating::ValueForMoneyScore.create(score: '1', description: "Test")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
::ValueForMoneyScore.create(score: '1', description:"Terrible, definitely not worth what was paid!")
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is descriptive enough in this case, the class `RatingsValueForMoneyScore` pretty much doesn't exist. Check your namespace, you have a class name (which should be singular) `Rating`, and the module `ValueForMoneyScore`. You'd use either

(after renaming the class to `Rating`)

`Rating.create(...)`

or

`ValueForMoneyScores.create(...)`

Your syntax is equivalent to:

```
class Rating
  module ValueForMoneyScores < ApplicationRecord
    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks. So if I follow correctly, my model is now `models/rating/value_for_money_score.rb' (singular), and within the `rating.rb` model i now have the following:                                                 `class Rating
 module ValueForMoneyScore < ApplicationRecord
    
  end
end` I tried now running `$ ValueForMoneyScore.create(score: '1', description:"Terrible, definitely not worth what was paid!")` in the console and I get the same error?